# Heroku claims to be up-to-date, but not showing files

Tags: git, heroku

Git is saying everything is up-to-date, but there's a difference in the files I see locally.  I recently updated the name of my app on Heroku, and believe I have properly updated the remote git configs.

### Attempt to push:

```
$ git push -f staging
Everything up-to-date
```

### `git config -l`:

```
remote.staging.url=git@heroku.com:s-si.git
remote.staging.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
```

### `ls` of the Heroku files:

```
heroku run bash -a s-si
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.2567
~ $ ls apps/
application  boston  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  main  newyork  rampup  startup_institute
```

### `ls` of my local files:

```
$ ls apps/
__init__.py       __init__.pyc      app_app           application       boston            newyork           payments          rampup            startup_institute
```

Comment: `heroku releases` will show you the current release. Does that sha match your local sha?

Comment: @Will:  No, it doesn't.  Hmmmm ... That commit is from more than a day ago.  Is it possible that the problem comes from a cross-branch merge?  I had some confusion about which branch to merge in before I pushed to staging.

Ah-ha!  Think I just figured it out:  When I updated the name of the Heroku app from the command line, Heroku blew away the config remote.staging.push dev:master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku removed my git config `remote.staging.push dev:staging` after I updated the name of the app from the command line, following these official instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps